# Explanation of "typeof SomeClass" as a return parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

`typeof` in JS returns a string. `Sequelize` has return types of `typeof Model` in it's TypeScript typings. What does this mean/do? I am unable to find an explanation in the docs.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/830357553d15ecf41652ec997926bd5cf442eb17/types/lib/sequelize.d.ts#L1021

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/830357553d15ecf41652ec997926bd5cf442eb17/types/lib/model.d.ts#L311

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name represents the instance type for a class (ie the type of the result of this expression for example `new Model()`).

But the class itself has a type as well. This type contains the constructor signature as well as the static members of the class. To get this type you need to use `typeof ClassName`.

A function returning `typeof Model` means it will return a new class (not a instance of a class) that is derived from `Model`.

Probably what you can then do is instantiate the class:

```
let myModelClass = define(...);
let myModelInstance = new myModelClass()
```

**Note** If you ever need the instance type of a class defined like this you will need to use `InstanceType<typeof myModelClass>`. This is due to the fact that only a class declaration adds a type with the same name, a variable will not in any way define such a type. It might help to define a type alias for it to make things work in a more expected way:

```
let myModel = define(...);
type myModel = InstanceType<typeof myModel>
let myModelInstance: myModel = new myModel()
```